# Can we instruct power bi to plot a horizontal bar graph from the python script in linux and retrieve the plotted graph from power bi?

Tags: python, linux, powerbi

I would like to pass two lists as inputs to powerbi for plotting horizontal bargraph(the same way we do in matplotlib) and retrieve the graph plotted by powerbi  within the python program? Is there any api for it? I don't want to use powerbi desktop.

I tried searching the same question on chatgpt ,I got answers like powerbi api does not provide any such capabilities in api's that are available. Is it true?

Comment: Why not just use matplotlib?